Power BI API - Get errors of dataset refresh - "refresh date" and "next refresh date"
Is it possible to get, through the Power BI API, the error content that is displayed on the Dataset view in the columns "Refreshed" and "Next refresh"?
In the UI, the first one is available when you click on the caution icon and go to details (source error like a table in the database doesn't exist).
The second is displayed directly in the tooltip and is often: "Due to consecutive errors, scheduled refresh has been disabled. Please resolve the error on the dataset and then re-enable."

Try to use the Power BI API to get the refresh history for a dataset.This link can help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-refresh-history#completed-refresh-example
However, keep in mind that you cannot call the API natively during runtime and when you  use PQ within the same dataset refresh it will provide the history up to the current refresh.
One solution is to create a separate report that calls the necessary APIs for all required datasets. This report would display the API call results and refresh its dataset on-demand.
You can  make real-time API calls using a caller like paginated reports like in this link :
https://medium.com/riccardo-perico/interactive-api-calls-from-power-bi-report-3e488ca8ffb6
